# Obtain just the current module's name in Python

Tags: python, module

How can you just obtain the current module's name in Python.

```
print(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Results in output of the form:

```
<module 'MODULE_NAME' from 'C:\\file_path_to_module_name\\MODULE_NAME.py'>
```

I just want to print `MODULE_NAME`

Comment: What about `__name__`?

Comment: `print(__name__)`

Comment: `__name__` prints the current context, like `__main__`, so that's not the answer. Reopened, and answered now that I understood.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/import.html#__file__) which gives full path of the module file (if saved to disk) and transform it using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) functions:

```
import os

print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
```

Comment: More elegant and concise than using os is a solution using pathlib: print(Path(__file__).stem)